# How we make Imageview like Trapezium

Tags: swift, calayer

I want to make image like trapezium or Quadilateral [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsU67.png). And set Image on trapezium.

```
 let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width, y: self.view.bounds.height/2 - 60)) // 50
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.bounds.size.width - 85)) // 80
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. We are not writing code for you.

Comment: Use a masklayer and UIBezierPath (with should be quite easy for a simple form like this one).

Comment: unexpectable to do this without a single try.Please share your tries with the community for better help.

Comment: @Larme Please help

Comment: @VarunSinghal . this is the answer which i have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func addDiamondMask(to view: UIView)
        {

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width, y: self.view.bounds.height/2 - 60))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.bounds.size.width - 85)) 
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        view.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
```

usage :   `addDiamondMask(to: imageView)`

Comment: @VarunSinghal. what is the height of ur image

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your imageView IBOutlet is named as `imgView`. Then you can use this code to create any shape for your image view.

```
func createShape() {
    path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.imgView.frame.width/2, y: 0.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.imgView.frame.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.imgView.frame.size.width, y: self.imgView.frame.size.height))
    path.close()
    let mask = CAShapeLayer();
    mask.frame = imgView.bounds;
    mask.path = path.cgPath;
    imgView.layer.mask = mask;
}
```

This example will create a triangular imageview.